# Integrating $\int^b_a [x]\,dx+\int^b_a [-x]\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I came across a question today...

> Integrate $\int^b_a [x]\,dx+\int^b_a [-x]\,dx$ where [.] denotes greatest integer function is equal to

Now [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485018/how-to-integrate-greatest-integer-function-int1-5-0-lfloor-x2-rfloor) question is not helpful for me because in that question limits are integers but here, $a$ and $b$ can be any real number.

I know how greatest integers work but I don't know how to integrate them. I even  tried to plot [their graphs](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+ceil(x)+and+ceil(-x)) but they didn't helped me either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* For all real numbers which are not an integer,
$$
[x] + [-x] = -1
$$

Comment: ok understood but can we really integrate a greatest integer function from limits a to b

Comment: @manshu: It is Riemann/Lebesgue integrable (continuous with the exception of finitely many points), and therefore you can combine the two integrals into a single one for the sum.

Comment: So it means that we can't solve $\int^b_a [x]\,dx$ ?

Comment: @manshu: If you mean "solve by writing an explicit formula": Yes, you can do that. But you don't *need* it for this question.