# Evaluating $\int_0^a \lfloor x^n \rfloor \,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate $\int_0^a \lfloor x^n \rfloor \,\mathrm{d}x$ (where $ \lfloor \,\cdot\, \rfloor $ denotes greatest integer function).

Can anyone please give a detailed explanation of how to do this? 
This is my first question on MathStack Exchange.

Thank You

Comment: This may help - [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408953/what-is-the-greatest-integer-function-and-how-do-you-integrate-it?rq=1)  and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485018/how-to-integrate-greatest-integer-function-int1-5-0-lfloor-x2-rfloor?rq=1) as the related questions!!

Answer (score 2):

If you mean $$ \begin{align} 
\int_{0}^{\infty}\lfloor x^n\rfloor dx,
\end{align} $$
then this integral diverges to infinity for all $ n\in\mathbb{R} $. To see this, I suggest making a comparison between $ \int_{0}^{\infty}\lfloor x^n\rfloor dx $ and $ \int_{0}^{\infty} x^n dx $, then using the [integral test for convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence).

Comment: In that test how can we relate the decreasing nature of the integral!, as here the step function is increasing? should we interchange the limits of integration as by then the functions seems to be decreasing?

Comment: For the cases that not decreasing, it is obvious to see that it diverges. The integral test for convergence is only for the cases where $ n<0 $.

Answer (score 1):

For a given $a\geq0$ there should $\exists k \in \mathbb{N}: \color{red}{k}\leq a^{n}<\color{red}{k}+1$ (i.e. $k=\left \lfloor  a^n\right \rfloor$) then 
$$\int\limits_0^a \lfloor x^n \rfloor dx=
\int\limits_0^1 \lfloor x^n \rfloor dx+
\int\limits_1^{\sqrt[n]{2}} \lfloor x^n \rfloor dx+
\int\limits_{\sqrt[n]{2}}^{\sqrt[n]{3}} \lfloor x^n \rfloor dx+...+
\int\limits_{\sqrt[n]{\color{red}{k}}}^{a} \lfloor x^n \rfloor dx\tag{1}$$
and we have

- for $x\in[0,1) \Rightarrow x^n\in[0,1) \Rightarrow \lfloor x^n \rfloor=0 \Rightarrow \int\limits_0^1 \lfloor x^n \rfloor dx=0$
- for $x\in[1,\sqrt[n]{2}) \Rightarrow x^n\in[1,2) \Rightarrow \lfloor x^n \rfloor=1 \Rightarrow \int\limits_1^{\sqrt[n]{2}} \lfloor x^n \rfloor dx=\sqrt[n]{2}-1$
- for $x\in[\sqrt[n]{2},\sqrt[n]{3}) \Rightarrow x^n\in[2,3) \Rightarrow \lfloor x^n \rfloor=2 \Rightarrow \int\limits_{\sqrt[n]{2}}^{\sqrt[n]{3}} \lfloor x^n \rfloor dx=2\left(\sqrt[n]{3}-\sqrt[n]{2}\right)$
- ...
- for $x\in[\sqrt[n]{t},\sqrt[n]{t+1}) \Rightarrow x^n\in[t,t+1) \Rightarrow \lfloor x^n \rfloor=t \Rightarrow \int\limits_{\sqrt[n]{t}}^{\sqrt[n]{t+1}} \lfloor x^n \rfloor dx=t\left(\sqrt[n]{t+1}-\sqrt[n]{t}\right)$
- ...
- for $x\in[\sqrt[n]{\color{red}{k}},a) \Rightarrow x^n\in[\color{red}{k},a^n) \Rightarrow \lfloor x^n \rfloor=\color{red}{k} \Rightarrow \int\limits_{\sqrt[n]{\color{red}{k}}}^{a} \lfloor x^n \rfloor dx=\color{red}{k}\left(a-\sqrt[n]{\color{red}{k}}\right)$

then $(1)$ becomes 
$$\int\limits_0^a \lfloor x^n \rfloor dx=
\left(\sum\limits_{t=1}^{\color{red}{k}-1}t\left(\sqrt[n]{t+1}-\sqrt[n]{t}\right)\right) + \color{red}{k}\left(a-\sqrt[n]{\color{red}{k}}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand what this integral means. Assume for simplicity that $a$ is a positive integer, say $a=3$, and that, e.g. $n=2$. Then draw the graph of the integrand
$$f(x):=\lfloor x^n\rfloor\qquad(0\leq x\leq a)\ ,$$
and shade the area you want to compute. You shall see that you don't need the fundamental theorem of calculus, since $f$ is a step function, and this area is a sum of rectangular pieces. The final result will not be a simple expression in the parameters $a$ and $n$, but a  sum of about $a^n$ terms.